# Get Category name from Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Is it possible to get the category name of a category given the Post ID, the following code works to get the Category Id, but how can I get the name?

```
<?php $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( 4 ); echo $post_categories[0]?>
```

Thank!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

here you go `get_the_category( $post->ID );` will return the array of categories of that post you need to loop through the array

```php
$category_detail=get_the_category('4'); // $post->ID
foreach($category_detail as $cd){
    echo $cd->cat_name;
}
```

[get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: thanks but where do I define the post ID in that code, that I want the category name of.

Comment: I don't like how you have to iterate over the array to get the name but it works.

Answer (score 42):

```
echo '<p>'. get_the_category( $id )[0]->name .'</p>';
```

is what you maybe looking for.

Comment: THANKS!! Exactly what I needed -  no loops - much prettier

Comment: Thanks ... It returns the post category name on which post we are

Comment: it is really good, if no need to use loop, e.g. in single post template. Nice.

Comment: Thank you for this. Easiest answer.

Answer (score 5):

doesn't

```
<?php get_the_category( $id ) ?>
```

do just that, inside the loop?

For outside:

```php
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
var_dump($categories);
```

Comment: That returns an array for me -  not the name of the category

Comment: how can you transform the Array of categories into a String?

Answer (score 3):

```
function wp_get_post_categories( $post_id = 0, $args = array() )
{
   $post_id = (int) $post_id;
   $defaults = array('fields' => 'ids');
   $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
   $cats = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, 'category', $args);

   return $cats;
}
```

Here is the second argument of function `wp_get_post_categories()` 
which you can pass the attributes of receiving data.

```
$category_detail = get_the_category( '4',array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ); //$post->ID
foreach( $category_detail as $cd )
{
   echo $cd->name;
}
```

Comment: I prefer your method (first one you did) because you can pass any taxonomy into that you want.  Default being 'category' of course, but if you custom post types and custom taxonomies then the accepted answer to this OP question is actually not going to suffice.  get_the_category() will only search for taxonomy 'category'.  Whereas your posted method can be passed the taxonomy.  Well played, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can a single line to echo out the category name by passing the post ID simply by using this:

```php
echo wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'category')[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_the_category()` function.

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( 4 );
$categories = get_the_category($post_categories[0]);
var_dump($categories);
```

Comment: @user1937021 have you checked the output ??

Comment: is it a post id ?? $post_categories[0]) ??

Comment: well 4 is the post id I want the category of

Comment: This returns an array

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php  
     // in woocommerce.php
     $cat = get_queried_object();
     $cat->term_id;
     $cat->name;
     ?>

    <?php
    // get product cat image
        if ( is_product_category() ){
            $cat = get_queried_object();
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            if ( $image ) {
                echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
            }       
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First Category name by post id

```
$first_category = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' )[0]->name;
```

Comment: Why are you using 'product_cat'?

Comment: This is the category slug. if your category slug name is 'category' then you can use the 'category' instead of 'product_cat'

Comment: Also, woo-commerce give us the 'product_cat' category name by-default

Comment: Exactly, why have you suddenly brought WooCommerce into it? The poster didn’t mention WooCommerce stall, which isn’t going to help them as they don’t want the product category

Comment: It just a name. doesn't matter what's your category name just put your category name and you will get the result. 
and I just reply answer to your query that why I used the product_cat name

Comment: I'm not the person who asked this question. What I'm trying to do is point out to you that you've suddenly introduced a WooCommerce specific term for no reason, which is very likely going to confuse the original poster.