# How to show view icon, comment and category on each post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

[image]I want to show total view and comment to each post on my website. 
http://storybuzz.in/

am using wordpress and theme is newsmag.

if am go to any post page its show view and comment on bottom of title.
[http://storybuzz.in/post/](http://storybuzz.in/right-heres-virat-reacted-ishant-mocked-steve-smith-hilarious-means/)

Comment: can you show us your *try* so far ?

Comment: you need to add hook to store post view count

Comment: may be i am new in WordPress

Comment: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/cache/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303840/get-category-name-from-post-id

Comment: @susheelsahoo have a look and follow above links, it will help you what you want.